# How can I pass a tuple with a single string as an argument (e.g. to mulitprocessing.Process)?

Tags: python, string, multiprocessing, arguments

I'm trying to pass a string argument to a target function in a process.  Somehow, the string is interpreted as a list of as many arguments as there are characters.

This is the code:

```
import multiprocessing

def write(s):
   print s

write('hello')

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=write, args=('hello'))

p.start()
```

I get this output:

```
hello
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/multiprocessing/process.py", line 237, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: write() takes exactly 1 argument (5 given)

>>>
```

What am I doing wrong? How am I supposed to pass a string?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel My question is older, so the referred question should be the one to get the "already has an answer yere" note.

Comment: No; duplicate closure does not in fact work that way. There are many references I could link you to on Meta about this; for example https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841. The closure is this way around because, among other things, the other question actually *identifies* the problem, rather than simply being caused by it. I already had to edit the title here in the hope of not click-baiting people with an actual `multiprocessing` issue; `multiprocessing` is irrelevant to what happened here.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

This is a common gotcha in Python - if you want to have a tuple with only one element, you need to specify that it's actually a tuple (and not just something with brackets around it) - this is done by adding a comma after the element.

To fix this, just put a comma after the string, inside the brackets:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=write, args=('hello',))
```

That way, Python will recognise it as a tuple with a single element, as intended. Currently, Python is interpreting your code as just a string. However, it's failing in this particular way because a string is effectively list of characters. So Python is thinking that you want to pass ('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'). That's why it's saying "you gave me 5 parameters".

Answer (score 16):

Change `args=('hello')` to `args=('hello',)` or even better `args=['hello']`. Otherwise parentheses don't form a sequence.

Answer (score 11):

You have to pass

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=write, args=('hello',))
```

Notice the comma! Otherwise it is interpreted as a simple string and not as a 1 element tuple.