# python: calling method over multiple instances parallelly

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am trying to parallel calling the same method over multiple instances, where instances are referring to the same object.

Sorry for this confusion statements.

Specifically, I want to change the following for-loop to parallel execution:

```
for i in range(len(instances)):#instances is a list of instances
   instances[i].do_some_computation_over_a_dataset()
```

Is it possible?

**Note for future readers:**

The above code is not the way to iterate over a collection of instances in Python. This is how to iterate in a sequential (ie non-parallel) way:

```
for i in instances:
    i.do_some_computation_over_a_dataset()
```

Comment: @quamrana , I want to ensure all instances have finished the method.

Comment: What makes you think that `Pool` doesn't wait?

Comment: @quamrana , I do not know `Pool` very much, just guess.

Comment: The first code example in here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html obviously waits for all processes to finish so that it can print all the results.

Comment: Ok, @quamrana thanks. Possible there is a difference between this question and you linked question? Here we want to call the same method in multiple instances while there they call the same method over different parameters.

Comment: Just don't add any parameters. (or you may have to add an empty tuple: (,) ? )

Comment: You mean `zip(*pool.map(calc_stuff, (,)))` ? But how can `calc_stuff ` be a method over multiple instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, let's do it. First the code([multiprocessing docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)):

```
In [1]: from multiprocessing import Process

In [2]: def f():
   ...:     print(1)
   ...:     for i in range(100):
   ...:         # do something
   ...:         pass
   ...:

In [3]: p1 = Process(target=f)

In [4]: p1.start()

1
In [5]: p2 = Process(target=f)

In [6]: p2.start()

1
In [7]: import time

In [8]: def f():
   ...:     for i in range(100):
   ...:         print(i)
   ...:         # do something
   ...:         time.sleep(1)
   ...:         pass
   ...:
In [9]: p1 = Process(target=f)
In [9]: p1 = Process(target=f)

In [10]: p1.start()

0
In [11]: p2 1
= Process(target=f)2
3
4
5
In [11]: p2 = Process(target=f)

In [12]: 6
p2.7
start8
In [12]: p2.start()

0
In [13]: 9
```

This is an example of how a function can be called in parallel. From `In [10]: p1.start()` you can see the output gets jumbled because program p1 is running in parallel while we run program p2.

When running the program in a Python script you want to make sure script only ends when all the programs have executed successfully. You can do this by

```
def multi_process(instance_params, *funcs):
   process = []
   for f in funcs:
       prog = Process(target=f, args=instance_params)
       prog.start()
       process.append(prog)
   for p in process:
       p.join()

multi_process(params, f, f)
```

Python doesn't have C++ or Java like multithreading support because of GIL. [Read about it here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). Though if your program is such that it does more I/O operations then CPU intensive tasks then you can use multithreading. For performing CPU intensive tasks multiprocessing is recommended.

In comment @ytutow asked what is difference between *pool of workers* and *process*. From [Pymotw](https://pymotw.com/3/multiprocessing/communication.html#process-pools):

> The Pool class can be used to manage a fixed number of workers for
>   simple cases where the work to be done can be broken up and
>   distributed between workers independently.
>
> The return values from the jobs are collected and returned as a list.
>
> The pool arguments include the number of processes and a function to
>   run when starting the task process (invoked once per child).

You can use Pool as:

```
def your_instance_method(instance):
   instances.do_some_computation_over_a_dataset()

with Pool(3) as p:
    instances = [insatnce_1, instance_2, instance_3]
    print(p.map(your_instance_method, instances))
```

About the correct number of workers, it's gereral recommendation to have 2*cpu_cores number of workers.

Comment: Thanks! What the difference between `multi_process` and `multiprocessing ` library in python?

Comment: The multiple instances will run the same method over some dataset, for example, compute the mean. I believe it is CPU intensive task.

Comment: @ytutow thats its CPU intensive task. Use `multiprocessing` its Python's standard library. I am not sure if there is any mulit_process module in Python. Is it a 3rd party module?

Comment: Sorry I am not very familiar with `multiprocessing `

Comment: @ytutow The answer gives an example of how you can use it. Read the docs I have attached for more info. Does this answer your question? If yes, you can mark this as accepted?

Comment: Thanks, give me some time for me read and understand this.

Comment: Hi @Amit Tripathi What is the difference between `from multiprocessing import Pool` and `from multiprocessing import Process`, or `Pool` and `Process`, does prior one not suitable for this task?

Comment: @ytutow see the edit to the answer for difference between the two.

Comment: Hi @Amit Tripathi , You mean `Pool` may break some tasks? And is better for simple tasks?

Comment: Hi @Amit Tripathi, sorry I missed a problem, how can I pass a list of `instance[i].call_method` to `multi_process `?

Comment: I have edited the answer for passing the arguments see this SO question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559125/string-arguments-in-python-multiprocessing. I also suggest that you read the docs once. It will clear your doubt.

Answer (score 2):

This code seems to show the difference between a `for` loop and `Pool`, calling a method on different instances:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

instances = ['a','ab','abc','abcd']


def calc_stuff(i):
    return len(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print('One at a time')
    for i in instances:
        print(len(i))

    print('Use Pool')
    with Pool(4) as pool:
        print(pool.map(calc_stuff, instances))
```

Note the use of `if __name__ == '__main':`

This separates each process out.

Output:

```
One at a time
1
2
3
4
Use Pool
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```